# negative infinite value in integration by parts

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate

$$\int_{a}^{b}(b-x)\,\ln(b-x)dx$$
Integrating by parts gives the following:

$$-\frac{1}{2}b^2\ln \left(b-x\right)+bx\ln \left(b-x\right)-\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln \left(b-x\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(b-x\right)^2$$

Now I know that I need to use TFC. I have no problem evaluating at the lower point but I feel uncomfortable evaluating at $b$. $\ln(0)$ is negative infinity right?

Edit: Wolfram Alpha seems to show that $x^2$ term would dominate but why is that true?

Comment: Consider the $\lim_\limits{x\to b} -\frac 12 (b-x)^2\ln(b-x) \cdots$

Answer (score 2):

You should have kept the expression factored (this is often good advice) as: $$-\frac{1}{2}(b-x)^2\ln(b-x)+\frac{1}{4}(b-x)^2$$And as $x\to b^-$ the $(b-x)$ term goes to zero ‘faster’ than the logarithm term, so there is no issue with $-\infty$. Formally, $\lim_{x\to0}x^2\ln x=0$, so you can safely ignore that term when evaluating at $b$ (strictly speaking we shouldn’t “evaluate” *at* $b$, since this integral is not a proper Riemann integral (the FTC is only for proper integrals) - it is an improper integral, defined in the Riemann calculus to be the limit of $\int_a^t\cdots$ as $t\to b^-$)

Comment: oh cool. thanks. I posted my edit before seeing you had responded